# Selecting only the entries that have a distinct combination of values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, links1, that has the columns headers CardID and AbilityID, that looks like this:

```
CardID | AbilityID
1001   | 1
1001   | 2
1001   | 3

1002   | 2
1002   | 3
1002   | 4

1003   | 3
1003   | 4
1003   | 5
```

What I want is to be able to return all the CardID that that have two specific AbilityID.

For example:

> If I choose 1 and 2, it returns 1001.
>   If I choose 3 and 4, it returns 1002 and 1003.

Is it possible to do this with only one table, or will I need to create an identical table and do an INNER JOIN on those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try self join:

```
SELECT t1.CardID 
FROM links1 AS t1 
JOIN links1 AS t2 
ON t1.CardID = t2.CardID 
WHERE t1.AbilityID = 1 AND t2.AbilityID = 2;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91836/5)

Answer (score 2):

```
You can try nested query,in your case
SELECT cid FROM
    (
        SELECT cid,COUNT(cid) AS total FROM links WHERE aid = 1 OR aid = 2
        GROUP BY cid
    ) AS t1 WHERE total%2 = 0;
```